# Поворот экрана после вызова intent с типом image/*

Tags: android

Приложение полностью имеет портретный режим.

Требуется загрузить картинку через intent с типом `image/*`.

Для теста проблемы требуется включить авто-поворот экрана.

Запускается intent => запускается галерея => выбираем картинку => переход снова в приложение => поворачиваем телефон => экран поворачивается, соответственно стираются все данные (вызов `onCreate()`) => через пару секунд возвращается снова в портретный режим.

В чем проблема понятно, открывается интерфейс android, в котором разрешен поворот и, видимо, после выбора изображения "поворотник" какое-то время слушает android, а не настройки моего приложения.

В xml у layout: `android:orientation="vertical"`

У activity в Manifest: `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

В коде activity: `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Ничего из этого, естественно, не помогает.
Итого вопрос, как это исправить?

Comment: Ну а исправить то что надо? Проблема в чём?

Comment: Вам наверное поможет информация о LiveData и ViewModel

Comment: "соответственно стираются все данные" -- вот это наверное и надо исправить. См. Saving State и Restoring State вот здесь как пример: https://medium.com/hootsuite-engineering/handling-orientation-changes-on-android-41a6b62cb43f

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, мне не подходит метод с сохранением State. О LiveData и ViewModel я знаю. В моем случае это будет костылем. Мне требуется избежать самого поворота экрана.